# Regex matching multiple pattern

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have these

```
name

name[one]

name[one][two]

name[one][two][three]
```

I want to be able to match them like this:

```
[name]

[name, one]

[name, one, two]

[name, one, two, three]
```

Here's [my regex I've tried](http://regex101.com/r/mF8pC8/2):

```
/([\w]+)(?:(?:\[([\w]+)\])+)?/
```

I just can't quite to seem to get it right, only gets the last square brackets

Comment: What language or program are you using for the RegEx implementation? (eg. Sed, PHP, Python, Notepad++)

Comment: PHP, that website converts it to php for when I am done testing

Comment: Try `([\w]+)(?:(?:\[([\w]+)\])\+)?`. There's a \ before last +.

Comment: Is there a max number of these groups or does it end at 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do `([\w]+)(?:\[([\w]+)\]\+)?`

http://regex101.com/r/mF8pC8/3

Changes from original regex - removed extra capture and added `\` before last `+`.

```
    1st Capturing group ([\w]+)
        [\w]+ match a single character present in the list below
            Quantifier: Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
            \w match any word character [a-zA-Z0-9_]
            (?:\[([\w]+)\]\+)? Non-capturing group
        Quantifier: Between zero and one time, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
        \[ matches the character [ literally
    2nd Capturing group ([\w]+)
        [\w]+ match a single character present in the list below
        Quantifier: Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
        \w match any word character [a-zA-Z0-9_]
        \] matches the character ] literally
        \+ matches the character + literally
    g modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a dynamic number of captures; the number of captures is exactly equal to the number of capture parenthesis pairs (`(?:...)` don't count). You have two capture parenthesis pairs, that means you get two captures - no more, no less.

To handle variable number of matches, use submatches (in a replace with a function, if your language supports that), or split.

You haven't labeled with a programming language, so this is as specific as I can go.

Comment: Dynamic number of captures is possible, but only in .NET. But what you say still applies here since the OP is using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can't repeat groups in a regex. You can write them out a number of times though. This works for up to three groups in square brackets. You can add more if you like.

```
(\w+)\[(\w+)\](?:\[(\w+)\])?(?:\[(\w+)\])?
```

Answer (score -1):

You can not have dynamic number of captures with php regexp...

Why not just, write something like: `explode('[',strtr('name[one][two][three]', [']'=>'']))` - it will give you desired result.